# Identifying weighted clusters with max distance diameter and sum(weight) > 50

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

#### Problem

Need to identify a way to find 2 mile clusters of points where each point has a value. Identify 2 mile areas which have a sum(value) > 50.

#### Data

I have data that looks like the following

```
ID        COUNT LATITUDE    LONGITUDE
187601546   20  025.56394   -080.03206
187601547   25  025.56394   -080.03206
187601548   4   025.56394   -080.03206
187601550   0   025.56298   -080.03285
```

Roughly 200K records.  What I need to determine is if there are any areas where more than sum of the count exceeds 65 in a one mile radius (2 mile diameter) area.

#### Using each point as a center for an area

Now, I have python code from another project that will draw a shapefile around a point of x diameter as follows:

```
def poly_based_on_distance(center_lat,center_long, distance, bearing):
# bearing is in degrees
# distance in miles
# print ('center', center_lat, center_long)

    destination = (vincenty(miles=distance).destination(Point(center_lat, 
       center_long), bearing).format_decimal())
```

And a routine to return destination and then see which points are inside the radius.

```
## This is the evaluation for overlap between points and 
    ## area polyshapes
    area_list = []
    store_geo_dict = {}
    for stores in locationdict:
        location = Polygon(locationdict[stores])

        for areas in AREAdictionary:
            area = Polygon(AREAdictionary[areass])
            if store.intersects(area):
                area_list.append(areas)

        store_geo_dict[stores] = area_list
        area_list = []
```

At this point, I am simply drawing a circular shapefile around each of the 200K points, see which others were inside and doing the count.

#### Need Clustering Algorithm?

However, there might be an area with the required count density where one of the points is not in the center.

I'm familiar with clustering algos such as DBSCAN that use attributes for classification but this is a matter of finding a density clusters using a value for each point.  Is there any clustering algorithm to find any cluster of a 2 mile diameter circle where the inside count is >= 50?

Any suggestions, python or R are preferred tools but this is wide-open and probably a one-off so computation efficiency is not a priority.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but maybe it will help simplify the problem depending on the distribution of your data. I will use planar coordinates and cKDTree in my example, this might work with geographic data if you can ignore curvature in a projection.

The main observation is the following: a point `(x,y)` does *not* contribute to a dense cluster if a ball of radius `2*r` (e.g. 2 miles) around `(x,y)` contributes less than the cutoff value (e.g. 50 in your title). In fact, any point within `r` of `(x,y)` does not contribute to ant dense cluster.

This allows you to *repeatedly* discard points from consideration. If you are left with no points, there are no dense clusters; if you are left with some points, clusters may exist.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# test data
N = 1000
data = np.random.rand(N, 2)
x, y = data.T

# test weights of each point
weights = np.random.rand(N)


def filter_noncontrib(pts, weights, radius=0.1, cutoff=60):
    tree = cKDTree(pts)
    contribs = np.array(
        [weights[tree.query_ball_point(pt, 2 * radius)].sum() for pt in pts]
    )
    return contribs >= cutoff


def possible_contributors(pts, weights, radius=0.1, cutoff=60):
    n_pts = len(pts)
    while len(pts):
        mask = filter_noncontrib(pts, weights, radius, cutoff)
        pts = pts[mask]
        weights = weights[mask]

        if len(pts) == n_pts:
            break

        n_pts = len(pts)

    return pts
```

Example with dummy data:

[image]

Comment: This actually doesn't work for the OP.  Imagine two points both of weight 30 that are three miles apart.  Your algo (check area of 2 miles around each point and sum weights) says that neither contribute to a dense cluster.  But if I move the centerpoint to halfway between the points.  I can draw a radius of two miles that enclose both points where the combined weight > 60 and thus satisfy the condition.

Comment: I agree with your example but the conclusion is not what I had in mind. Say you are looking for clusters with radius at most `1`. In that case, my suggestion is to check a radius of `2` around each point. If the combined weight in the radius of `2` is small, then the point is not in any dense cluster of radius `1` (ignoring boundary cases).

Comment: Sorry I missed the 2d (where d is the diameter).  I agree that your solution narrows down the search area but in this case it leaves me with 65% of the points in possible clusters.  My original code could handle the 2d case, I'm just looking for something that actually addresses the clustering weight issue directly.

Comment: Actually, I think there is a solution.  Find the midpoint between each and every point. Then run your routine using d (rather than 2d) to see possible clusters.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how you mean to use midpoints; thinking out loud, it is not true that every cluster is centered on a midpoint between a pair of original points. For example, take an equilateral triangle with side 1 and `r=sqrt(3)/6`.

Comment: This approach is probably already as expensive as finding the solution, because the query cost increases with the radius. So doing a 2r query for every point is more expensive than just doing a r radius query for each.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse makes sense; but how does one select candidate cluster centers that are not in the original set of points?

Comment: Well, there are probably infinitely many to choose from. Say you have radius 10, and your data is at (0,0) and (1,0) with weight 100 each. We could choose (10,0) and satisfy the conditions. So it is underspecified.

Comment: I'm thinking there is a scaling issue here which suggests the original request was underspecified.  The actual scaling parameters are most points weight between 2.5 and 15 while the threshold is 1,000 within the 1 mile radius.  So the equilateral triangle example is probably going to be an extreme edge case.  I think we are closer to hand grenades than pinpoint scalpels. 

Ultimately, this is a threshold question of do we meet this threshold -- yes or no. Beyond there is a question of how many and there is an additional specification label that I left out for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN can be adapted (see Generalized DBSCAN; define core points as weight sum >= 50), but it will not ensure the maximum cluster size (it computes transitive closures).

You could also try complete linkage. Use it to find clusters with the desired maximum diameter, then check if these satisfy the desired density. But that does not guarantee to find all.

It's probably faster to (a) build an *index* for fast radius search. (b) for every point, find neighbors in radius r; keep if they have the desired minimum sum. But that does not guarantee to find everything because the center is not necessarily a data point. Consider a max radius of 1, minimum weight 100. Two points with weight 50 each, at (0,0) and (1,1). Neither a query at (0,0) nor one at (1,1) will discover the solution,  but a cluster at (.5,.5) satisfies the conditions.

Unfortunately, I believe your problem is at least NP-hard, so you won't be able to afford the ultimate solution.